# Open child route with url in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have defined some routes

```
export const ContainerRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'container',
        component: containerComponent,
        children: [
            ...FirstRoutes,
            ...SecondRoutes
        ]
    }
];
```

First:

```
export const FirstRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'first',
        component: FirstComponent
    }
];
```

Second:

```
export const SecondRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'second',
        component: SecondComponent
    }
];
```

The container component is displayed in a router-outlet and a child itself. Its children are in a router outlet, too.

So, everything works while navigating to the first and the second component. But when I want to open the second one by url (`localhost:3000/#/parent/container/second`), it always redirects to `localhost:3000/#/parent/container/first`.

How can I achieve that it navigates to the second component?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

My mistake was that I navigated to the first in the container's ngOnInit method, because I wanted it as the first page.

Changing the container routes to

```
export const ContainerRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'container',
        component: containerComponent,
        children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'first',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
            ...FirstRoutes,
            ...SecondRoutes
        ]
    }
];
```

and deleting the navigation in OnInit solved my problem.